# Does an indefinite real Gram matrix have a square root?

Tags: matrices

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix. Let $D$ be a diagonal $n\times n$ matrix with diagonal entries either $\pm 1$. Does the "Gram matrix" $G(M,D) = (D M^T D) M$ have a square root even if this matrix has a negative eigenvalue? The latter possibility indeed happens: For instance consider $G\left(D=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1), M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right) = -I_2$, which indeed has two negative eigenvalues but also admits a non-principal square root.

I suspect that the eigenvalues which are not positive real numbers will pair up. In particular, I suspect that all negative real eigenvalues will have even multiplicity. I think the argument needs to use this fact somehow, but I'm not sure how. I think it'll probably extract the invariant subspaces of the block matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & DM^TD \\ M & 0\end{pmatrix}$ one at a time.